# How can I add properties to a class using a decorator that takes a list of names as argument?

Tags: python, decorator

I would like to add many dummy-properties to a class via a decorator, like this:

```
def addAttrs(attr_names):
  def deco(cls):
    for attr_name in attr_names:
      def getAttr(self):
        return getattr(self, "_" + attr_name)
      def setAttr(self, value):
        setattr(self, "_" + attr_name, value)
      prop = property(getAttr, setAttr)
      setattr(cls, attr_name, prop)
      setattr(cls, "_" + attr_name, None) # Default value for that attribute
    return cls
  return deco

@addAttrs(['x', 'y'])
class MyClass(object):
  pass
```

Unfortunately, the decoarator seems to keep the reference of `attr_name` instead of its content. Therefore, `MyClass.x` and `MyClass.y` access both `MyClass._y`:

```
a = MyClass()
a.x = 5
print a._x, a._y
>>> None, 5
a.y = 8
print a._x, a._y
>>> None, 8
```

What do I have to change to get the expected behavior?

Comment: The lack of (vertical) whitespace in all of the code examples is disturbing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You almost had it working.  There is just one nit.  When creating the inner functions, bind the current value of `attr_name` into the getter and setter functions:

```
def addAttrs(attr_names):
  def deco(cls):
    for attr_name in attr_names:
      def getAttr(self, attr_name=attr_name):
        return getattr(self, "_" + attr_name)
      def setAttr(self, value, attr_name=attr_name):
        setattr(self, "_" + attr_name, value)
      prop = property(getAttr, setAttr)
      setattr(cls, attr_name, prop)
      setattr(cls, "_" + attr_name, None) # Default value for that attribute
    return cls
  return deco

@addAttrs(['x', 'y'])
class MyClass(object):
  pass
```

This produces the expected result:

```
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.x = 5
>>> print a._x, a._y
5 None
>>> a.y = 8
>>> print a._x, a._y
5 8
```

Hope this helps.  Happy decorating :-)

Answer (score 3):

Python does not support block-level scoping, only function-level. Therefore, any variable assigned within the loop will be available outside the loop as the last available value. To get the result you are looking for, you will need to use a closure within the loop:

```
def addAttrs(attr_names):
  def deco(cls):
    for attr_name in attr_names:
      def closure(attr):
        def getAttr(self):
          return getattr(self, "_" + attr)
        def setAttr(self, value):
          setattr(self, "_" + attr, value)
        prop = property(getAttr, setAttr)
        setattr(cls, attr, prop)
        setattr(cls, "_" + attr, None)
      closure(attr_name)
    return cls
  return deco
```

Using the closure `closure`, the attributes assigned within `getAttr` and `setAttr` will be scoped correctly.

EDIT: corrected indentation