# How can I add a property inside a class decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm using a decorator to automatically add serializability to my Python classes. Now I'm wondering, if I could also set a property to the class I want to decorate inside the decorator.

```py
def serialize(clazz):
  def inner(actual_class_type):
    actual_init = actual_class_type.__init__

    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
      cool_thing = clazz()

      # do stuff

      actual_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

    actual_class_type.__init__ = new_init

    return actual_class_type

  return inner
```

Comment: Probably? What does your decorator look like?

Comment: @chepner Why would a specific code snippet be necessary? Is it dependent on the specific decorator implementation?

Comment: Because if your decorator defines a class and returns it, it should be trivial to add a property to that class definition. If not, then showing your code will make it clearer what you *are* doing and how you might modify it.

Comment: @chepner If it's trivial, then write an answer. Obviously it's not trivial to me.

Comment: I can't write an answer, because I don't know what your decorator looks like.

Comment: @chepner Does this help?

Comment: If that is intended to decorate a class, why does it return a function instead of a class?

Comment: @chepner Because I forgot a line in my questionware.

Comment: I also wonder about the down votes. I can't imagine it was because of the missing code, since I don't think it contributed anything. All I needed was a pointer to the `property()` buildin.

Comment: So, your question really didn't have anything to do with  the decorator, but how to add a property to a class?

Comment: @chepner Normally you would do it with the @ property decorator, which I knew about. So it did have to do with the special case of using a class decorator. Just not with my specific code, like I said in the beginning.

Comment: And that's a failure to understand what `@property` actually means. All of which is much easier to diagnose than forcing us to guess what you do and do not understand.

Comment: So my answer to the last comment was deleted. Not sure if the word "pee" offended anyone, but I guess we can just leave it at that. Emberassing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setattr(actual_class_type, attribute_name, default_value)`.

See the example here:
[How can I add properties to a class using a decorator that takes a list of names as argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125832/how-can-i-add-properties-to-a-class-using-a-decorator-that-takes-a-list-of-names)

```
def serialize(clazz):
  def inner(actual_class_type):
    actual_init = actual_class_type.__init__

    def new_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
      cool_thing = clazz()

      # do stuff

      actual_init(self, *args, **kwargs)

    actual_class_type.__init__ = new_init

    prop_name = "my_prop"
    def getAttr(self):
      return getattr(self, "_" + prop_name)
    def setAttr(self, value):
      setattr(self, "_" + prop_name, value)
    prop = property(getAttr, setAttr)
    setattr(cls, prop_name, prop)
    setattr(cls, "_" + prop_name, None) # Default value for that property

    return actual_class_type

  return inner
```

Comment: Your example adds an attribute, not a property. The linked questions accepted answer, however, actually does answer mine as well. Do you want to update your answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Actually I want to mark this question as duplicate but I think I don't have enough reputation to do that, but maybe you can do that as a creator. Updated an answer.

Comment: That's fair, I'll still at least give you an upvote, since you pointed me in the right direction. And an answer by Raymond Hettinger, no less.